How to use batchUpdate in Node.js
I am using the following method to access a Google Spreadsheet using Javascript to, for example, insert a row of data:
const Sheets = require("@googleapis/sheets");
const jwt = new Sheets.auth.JWT(xxemailxx, null, xxprivate keyxx, [...]);
await jwt.authorize();

const sheets = Sheets.sheets("v4");
sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    auth: jwt,
    spreadsheetId: "xxxxxxx",
    range: "Sheet1",
    resource: { values: [[1,2,3,4]]}
  }, (err, response) => {
   // ...callback
   }
});

Note that I pass the JWT in the API call. This method has worked well for some years. Now I want to use batchUpdate to append a block of rows. I can't find documentation for Node.js. The link in the @googleapis/sheets repo points to this and this which looks like it's for web service APIs. I tried various permutations to pass in a requestbody but was not successful.
What is a workable method to use the batchUpdate api? Is there documentation on batchUpdate more specific to Node.js?

RECOMMENDATION:
Here's the sample syntax that you can use for batchUpdate:
 sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
  
  "spreadsheetId": 'xxxxxxxx',
  "resource": {
    "valueInputOption": "RAW",
    "data": [
      {
        "range": "A1:C3", //A1 Notation
        "values": [
            ["Hi", "Google", "Docs"],
            ["Hey", "please", "update"],
            [1, 2, 3]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, function(error, res){
  if (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(res);
});


Note: Regardless of the authentication you will use, I believe the responseBody syntax will be the same.

References:

batchUpdate

batchUpdate:Values range



Works beautifully. Separately, I could use "A3" as `range and it appends the block of rows from that point onward.
